# rolling logs and specific arguments in python

Tags: python, logging, arguments

I would like to be able to implement some rolling logs (once a week rolling). Arguments such as the log name and log path should be passed through in my batch file. I would need to be able to leave out the log name whilst keeping the log path in the arguments and it would take a default value for the log name.

I have tried using the logging.basicConfig but cant seem to achieve the intended result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler
import inspect
import argparse

def rolling_logger(app_id: str = None, logger_name: str = None, logging_level=logging.INFO, path='C\\dir\\Logs\\',
               log_file='file_name.log'):
    """
    Handles writing to the log file with specific style rules applied.
    Rolling logs generates a new log file every week and stores onlu one weeks worth of old logs
    
    dir
        Logs
            file_name.log.20230814
            file_name.log
    """
    print(path, log_file)
    app_id_str = f"[app-id: {app_id}]" if app_id else ""
    fmt = f"%(asctime)s {app_id_str} %(levelname)s %(threadName)s %(filename)s %(message)s"

    if not logger_name:
        # gets the name of the module calling get_logger
        logger_name = inspect.getmodule(inspect.stack()[1][0]).__name__

    logger = logging.getLogger(logger_name)
    logger.setLevel(logging_level)

    for handler in logger.handlers[:]:
        logger.removeHandler(handler)

    rotating_handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler(path + '\\' + log_file, when='W6', backupCount=1) # specifies how many logs to keep and when to roll over
    rotating_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt))
    logger.addHandler(rotating_handler)

    return logger

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Parses path and log_file arguments')
parser.add_argument('--path', default='dir/logs', type=str, help='Path to logs')
parser.add_argument('--log_file', default='name.log', type=str, help='Log file name')
args = parser.parse_args()
logger = rolling_logger(path=args.path, log_file=args.log_file)
```

This should match your needs. The when='W6' specifies the day of the week 6 (indexed at 0) that the log should roll over on. So Sunday night at midnight.